# Zoom to Marker location on click -OpenLayers

Tags: onclick, zooming, openlayers, geojson, marker

I am displaying markers on the map from geojson file. In the current code, I can add the markers on the map. I want to add fly to or zoom in marker exact location upon click on the marker.how can I achieve that using OpenLayers.

```
var cityMarker = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
      url: "data/cities.js"
  }),
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
            anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
            anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
            anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
            scale:0.03,
            src: "icons/red-circle.png"
          })
      })  
});
map.addLayer(cityMarker);
```

Answer (score 1):

bind `singleclick` event to map

```
map.on('singleclick', event => {
 // get the feature you clicked
 const feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, (feature) => {
  return feature
 })
 if(feature instanceof ol.Feature){
   // Fit the feature geometry or extent based on the given map
   map.getView().fit(feature.getGeometry())
   // map.getView().fit(feature.getGeometry().getExtent())
 }
})
```

A separate HTML file for you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>GeoJSON</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css"
      type="text/css"
    />
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>
      var image = new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 5,
        fill: null,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: "red", width: 1 }),
      });

      var styles = {
        Point: new ol.style.Style({
          image: image,
        }),
      };

      var styleFunction = function (feature) {
        return styles[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
      };

      var geojsonObject = {
        type: "FeatureCollection",
        crs: {
          type: "name",
          properties: {
            name: "EPSG:3857",
          },
        },
        features: [
          {
            type: "Feature",
            geometry: {
              type: "Point",
              coordinates: [0, 0],
            },
          },
          {
            type: "Feature",
            geometry: {
              type: "Point",
              coordinates: [13369643, 3572500],
            },
          },
        ],
      };

      var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geojsonObject),
      });

      var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource,
        style: styleFunction,
      });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM(),
          }),
          vectorLayer,
        ],
        target: "map",
        controls: ol.control.defaults({
          attributionOptions: {
            collapsible: false,
          },
        }),
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 2,
        }),
      });
      map.on("singleclick", (event) => {
        // get the feature you clicked
        const feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, (feature) => {
          return feature;
        });
        if (feature instanceof ol.Feature) {
          // Fit the feature geometry or extent based on the given map
          map.getView().fit(feature.getGeometry());
          // map.getView().fit(feature.getGeometry().getExtent())
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can I bind a single click event with a marker rather than a map?

Comment: can you please give an example as I tried binding to the marker and using your code above but still not able to get the click event.

Comment: Sorry! There was something wrong with the previous code,I have modified it.

Comment: thank you this does works but I am looking for marker click event.

Comment: Feature can also bind singleclick event,get features first:const features = cityMarker.getSource().getFeatures()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220905/discussion-between-poonam-patel-and-fbfatboy).